# Problems when adding Itens on Strip Menu with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to insert some Serial Port names on a Strip Menu on Visual Studio (2017). The sample code bellow shows how I'm doing this.

```
        Dim spNames() As String = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()

        For Each spName As String In [spNames]
            PortaToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(spName)
        Next
```

But, when I run the code, I get the following text on strip menu item.
Here's a Picture that shows the problem:

[image]

> "COM6" & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & "ᄈ" & ChrW(4045) & "鮆" & ChrW(65535) & "ᄈ" & ChrW(4045) & "鮆" & ChrW(65535) & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & vbNullChar & ...

Why do this happens? What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks for Helping!

Comment: vba or vb.net? I guess the latter.

Comment: This junk comes from the registry, written there by the device driver.  Getting good drivers is never not a problem with cheap hardware.  Run Regedit.exe and navigate to HKLM/Hardware/DeviceMap/SerialComm.  Verify that you see COM6.  Unplug the USB device and press F5 to refresh the view.  Delete any junk values you see left behind.  Plug it back in, F5 again.  If the junk comes back then you need to take the device out to the parking lot and drive your car of it a few times.